# Floating keyboard for android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building a custom keyboard for Android, and I need it to float.
So, I need to be able to:
 * keep it on top of other applications
 * resize it and locate anywhere on the screen

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Thanks,
yakobom

Answer (score 1):

First, save the `Window` with `getWindow().getWindow()` in `InputMethodService`. Then use `Window.getAttributes()`, change the `WindowManager.LayoutParams`'s `x` and `y`, and call `Window.setAttributes()`. Implement dragging as usual.

[See the answer in the newer question for resizing and more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51038137/10477326):

Comment: I apologize, I have no way of checking it or making any use of this since this is ancient history... But I appreciate the effort!

Answer (score -1):

Check out the developers note on keyboard. [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.html)

They have various properties related to keyboard,where you can float your keyboard layout.

Comment: Hi, I couldn't find what you are referring to. Can you please try to direct me?