# Android floating keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, floating

Is it possible to change programmatically the position of the keyboard?
I'm developing an app for a totem, and if the keyboard appears docked on the bottom, it's very difficult to use.

I tried to create a custom keyboard extending the InputMethodService, and i'm able to change the layout of the keys, but i'm not able to change the keyboard's view position.

[SwiftKey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey)  allows to undock the keyboard and to drag it vertically, how can they do that?

Answer (score 1):

Inside InputMethodService, you have reference to a `Window`. Add your dragging logic to update `LayoutParams` for the `window`. Make sure you implement `onComputeInset` properly. On a note that the gravity of window is always CENTER horizontally and BOTTOM vertically even though you try to use a new `LayoutParams` for the `window`.

Check out my sample https://github.com/dbof10/float-keyboard
[image]

Comment: Please can you update your repo, it looks like very promising, but it's not working properly

Comment: what do you mean not working properly, can you create an issue in the repo?

Answer (score 0):

Put a KeyboardView inside a `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout` and on a `OnTouchListener` change its margins. For example

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
boolean performClick = false;

switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        moveToY = (int) (event.getRawY() - dy);
        moveToX = (int) (event.getRawX() - dx);
        params.topMargin = moveToY;
        params.leftMargin = moveToX;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
        performClick = false;
    break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        performClick = true;
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        dy = event.getRawY();
        dx = event.getRawX();
        performClick = true;
        break;
}
return !performClick; }
```

More detailed example of a Floating KeyboardView [here](https://github.com/GeorgeArgyrakis/FloatingKeyboard)

Comment: That doesn't help